# Email job scheduler query for generating daily report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> > **i have a job scheduler that is suppose to send a daily collection report to 20 different id's based on 20 different divisions. Each division will receive 1 report of that particular division only. This is the query i have come up with .**

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @xml = CAST((select tm.name as 'td','',h.name as 'td','',h.account_number AS 'td','', 
SUM(bc.total_amount)  AS 'td'  
FROM MJP.dbo.tbl_bank_collection bc,  
MJP.dbo.tbl_div_type_master tm,  
MJP.dbo.tbl_div_header h  
where   bc.type_id = tm.id    
and bc.header_id = h.id    
and bc.transaction_date = '06-12-2012'   
and bc.div_id in ( select d.id    
from tbl_div d, tbl_bank_collection bc    
where bc.div_id = d.id    
group by d.id)    
group by tm.name, h.name,h.account_number with rollup    
having grouping(h.name) = 1 or    
GROUPING(h.account_number) = 0     
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))   
SET @body ='<html><i>Collection Report</i>    
<body bgcolor=red><table border = 1><tr><th>Type Name    
<th>Header Name</th><th>Account Number</th>    
<th>Total Amount</th></tr>'     
SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'   
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    
@profile_name='alkesh mail',    
@body_format ='HTML',    
@recipients='id.no1@yahoo.com;id.no2@yahoo.com',    
@subject='Daily Report',    
@body=@body    


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now i want to split the report after a particular divison's final sum amount is calculated and the next report should be generated for the next division' id.

Any suggestions or clarifications !!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming business politics has you constrained within SQL Server, because concatenating XML email reports is ***not*** what SQL Server is designed for.

Personally I would have a service executable (Windows Service, or just  a Console Application called by task scheduler, whatever.) with code (e.g. C#) that:

1. Gets *just* the data form SQL Server, passing a divisionId paramter to get the report for *just* that division.
2. Open an XML template file and insert the data.
3. Request a list of users for that division from SQL Server, and email each person in the list.
4. Repeat for each division.

Having said all that you could do this with just stored procedures, using loops. You could use a cursor (yuck) but I always prefer these constructs: (NB. Looping in RDBMS's is something to be avoided really, it very much depends on your particular circumstances)

```
declare @divisionId int = (select min(divisionId) from tbDivisions)
declare @userId int = ( min(userId) from users where divisionId = @divisionId )
declare @xml nvarchar(max)

while divisionId is not null
begin
    exec your_report_stored_procedure @division = @divisionId, output @xml = @xmlOut

    while @userId is not null
    begin
        exec your_email_tored_procedure @userId = @userId, @xmlIn = @xml
        select @userId = min(userId) from users where divisionId = @divisionId and userId > @userId
    end

    select @divisionId = min(divisionId) from tbDivisions where divisionId > @divisionId
end
```